# Google analytics injected using TS does not work but it does using JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-analytics

I have my Angular site and I wanted to get google analytics added only when bundling the application for production. I extracted the code placed in the HTML into a TS file following this example:

https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1003397/Google-Analytics-Typescript

which made sense and looked pretty similar to the actual JS and I installed (I changed the ID to my site ID).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.analytics

to get the the types being loaded when compiling the site. The corresponding JS file gets generated but google analytics does not work. However if I place the original javascript that was on the HTML file into a JS file and add that, it just works.

So my question is, is there anything else to do when using the TS file?

Comment: You can enable debug mode on GA to see if the calls are actually going out when your application bootstraps.  That might help.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
export var gaNewElem : any = {};
export var gaElems : any = {};
```

*This changes the original code*. Don't do that. A proper way to reflect the existance of these variables is

```
declare var gaNewElem: any;
declare var gaElems:any;
```

Comment: your proposal didn't work unfortunately. I have to say that I am using webpack and I am referencing the types from the package @types/google.analytics which should be picked up when bundling but it isn't